# VMWare NSX loadbalancer seems to set Connection: closed header

Tags: http, iis, ntlm, haproxy, vmware-nsx

We have an IIS server that sits behind an NSX load balancer.

We're using NTLM to authenticate with IIS, but it's only working if I hit the server directly, and not if I hit it through the load balancer. This is coming from the same browser, just hitting different endpoints.

I put TCPTrace in between the load balancer and IIS, and the main difference in traffic I could see was that coming from the load balancer the `Connection: close` HTTP head was set, whereas going directly it was set to the normal `keep-alive`. I then researched NTLM a bit more, and it turns out that it's connection-oriented, so `Connection: close` isn't an option.

Is it possible the load balancer is changing the header? It's only configured through the VMWare/NSX UI, and there's nothing unusual in that config.

Other piece of info: the load balancer is an HTTPS endpoint; the IIS is listening on HTTP (as was TCPTrace).

**EDIT: the following rules (from [here [PDF]](https://communities.vmware.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/31772-3-156762/NSX-6.2-LB%20configuration%20examples-v1.1.pdf), page 43) have been applied to the load balancer, with no effect:**

`no option http-server-close`

`no option httpclose`

Comment: Hi, I'd say definitely the LB is changing the header.  Are there any client stickiness settings in the LB?  Sorry, I'm not so familiar with NSX LB.

Comment: @Adrien Yes, there are - it's sticky on source IP address. NSX LB is actually HA proxy, where some of the common config (such as sticky on source IP) is fronted by a UI. I can request the XML document that represents the full state of the LB config, if that's useful.